# TypeError: unicode() takes at most 3 arguments (8 given)

Tags: python, renpy

I'm defining characters in a new Ren'Py project, mostly just to learn how they work so I can use them in the future. When I started the game, it gave me an error message regarding the fourth line of my code, ending with "TypeError: unicode() takes at most 3 arguments (8 given)"
Here are the first four lines of my code:

```
# base
define base = Character(name="Base",voice_tag="base",who_suffix=":",ctc="ctc.png",ctc_position="nestled",who_color="#ffffff",window_background="txtbx_base.png")
# abc
define abc = Character(name="abc",kind="base",voice_tag="abc",who_color="#ffa5a5",who_font="game/gui/Annie_Use_Your_Telescope/AnnieUseYourTelescope-Regular.ttf",what_color="#ff7777",what_font="game/gui/Annie_Use_Your_Telescope/AnnieUseYourTelescope-Regular.ttf",window_background="txtbx_abc.png")
```

Can anyone help diagnose the problem?

Edit: Here is the full error it gave me:

```
I'm sorry, but an uncaught exception occurred.

While running game code:
  File "game/script.rpy", line 4, in script
    define abc = Character(name="abc",kind="base",voice_tag="abc",who_color="#ffa5a5",who_font="game/gui/Annie_Use_Your_Telescope/AnnieUseYourTelescope-Regular.ttf",what_color="#ff7777",what_font="game/gui/Annie_Use_Your_Telescope/AnnieUseYourTelescope-Regular.ttf",window_background="txtbx_abc.png")
  File "game/script.rpy", line 4, in <module>
    define abc = Character(name="abc",kind="base",voice_tag="abc",who_color="#ffa5a5",who_font="game/gui/Annie_Use_Your_Telescope/AnnieUseYourTelescope-Regular.ttf",what_color="#ff7777",what_font="game/gui/Annie_Use_Your_Telescope/AnnieUseYourTelescope-Regular.ttf",window_background="txtbx_abc.png")
TypeError: unicode() takes at most 3 arguments (8 given)

-- Full Traceback ------------------------------------------------------------

Full traceback:
  File "game/script.rpy", line 4, in script
    define abc = Character(name="abc",kind="base",voice_tag="abc",who_color="#ffa5a5",who_font="game/gui/Annie_Use_Your_Telescope/AnnieUseYourTelescope-Regular.ttf",what_color="#ff7777",what_font="game/gui/Annie_Use_Your_Telescope/AnnieUseYourTelescope-Regular.ttf",window_background="txtbx_abc.png")
  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\Desktop\renpy-7.3.5-sdk\renpy\ast.py", line 2108, in execute
    value = renpy.python.py_eval_bytecode(self.code.bytecode)
  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\Desktop\renpy-7.3.5-sdk\renpy\python.py", line 2052, in py_eval_bytecode
    return eval(bytecode, globals, locals)
  File "game/script.rpy", line 4, in <module>
    define abc = Character(name="abc",kind="base",voice_tag="abc",who_color="#ffa5a5",who_font="game/gui/Annie_Use_Your_Telescope/AnnieUseYourTelescope-Regular.ttf",what_color="#ff7777",what_font="game/gui/Annie_Use_Your_Telescope/AnnieUseYourTelescope-Regular.ttf",window_background="txtbx_abc.png")
  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\Desktop\renpy-7.3.5-sdk\renpy\character.py", line 1445, in Character
    return type(kind)(name, kind=kind, **properties)
TypeError: unicode() takes at most 3 arguments (8 given)

Windows-8-6.2.9200
Ren'Py 7.3.5.606
gonna  make some fancy textboxes and stuff 1.0
Thu Apr 14 16:46:13 2022
```

Comment: `kind` is not supposed to be a string, it's supposed to be an actual type object.

Comment: That seems to have fixed my error; thank you!